# Parallel transport around a closed loop

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, tensors, curvature, connections

Imagine an arbitrary closed loop in some **Riemannian manifold** $M$ with the **Levi-Civita connection** $\nabla$. If this curve $\gamma$ were infinitesimal (parametric distance ~ $\epsilon$) and given by 2 vector fields $U,V$, then starting from a point $A$ and parallel transporting some vector $W$ around the loop, we obtain the vector $$ \tau^{\gamma}_{A,A} W = W - \epsilon^2 R(U,V)W + \ldots$$
where $$ R(U,V) \equiv [\nabla_{U}, \nabla_{V}] - \nabla_{[U,V]} $$ is the **curvature tensor** and $$ \tau^{\gamma}_{A,A}: T_AM \rightarrow T_AM $$ is the **operator of parallel transport** around $\gamma$.

My question is, is it possible to find such an operator (explicitly) for a general non-infinitesimal loop? I tried to decompose the loop into infinitesimal loops (as if in Kelvin-Stokes theorem) and to construct the operator from them, but I am stuck at how to traverse the infinitesimal loops. I guess the operator should somehow depend on the curvature tensor, since it is an identity for vanishing curvature. What is the dependence?

N.B.: This is not a homework question. I am just curious.

Comment: Hello, so I am wondering if the dot product $g(u,v)$, where $u\in T_pM$ is a vector of the tangent space of a Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$ at a given point $p\in M$ and $v\in T_pM$ is the parallel transport along a closed curve on $M$, only depends on the curvature of $(M,g)$ along that closed curve. And, if so, is there a formula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not in general. Such map is actually called holonomy. See [holonomy](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holonomy?wprov=sfla1).